# problem with stacked bargraph in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

Can someone help me to add labels in the middle of each piece.

```
library(ggplot2)

a <- c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4")
b <- c("AA","AA","AA","AA","BB","BB","BB","BB","CC","CC","CC","CC")
c <- c(40,45,55,52,70,84,81,60,70,79,90,88)
mat <- data.frame(a,b,c)

g <- ggplot(mat, aes(a,c, fill=b)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
     geom_text(aes(y=c, label=c), colour="yellow")
g
```

Comment: btw I would recommend not to use object names that equal R function names like `c` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is more a stackoverflow-question ;-)

You can use `dplyr` and then compute a cumulative frequency for each bar, subtracting half of the frequencies (half = middle). Then you have to use this new vector as y-aes for `geom_text`.

```
library(ggplot2)

a <-c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4") 
b <-c("AA","AA","AA","AA","BB","BB","BB","BB","CC","CC","CC","CC") 
c <-c(40,45,55,52,70,84,81,60,70,79,90,88) 
mat <-data.frame(a,b,c)

library(dplyr)
mat <- mat %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(ypos = cumsum(c) - .5*c)

g <-ggplot(mat, aes(a,c, fill=b)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(y=ypos, label=c), colour="yellow")
g
```

[image]